# I'm wondering how a virtual machine saves files on hardware

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I recently used a virtual machine (Oracle vm virtualbox) to use Ubuntu on my Windows laptop. I wrote helloworld.c for testing my new OS, and saved it. I wondered "Can I see the file's directory (helloworld.c) on my Windows laptop?"

So I checked my virtualbox directory (C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox), because I thought helloworld.c was saved there. But it wasn't. Where can I find it?

My laptop has a 256GB HDD. And when I setup my virtual machine, I allocated 30GB. If helloworld.c is saved, it is saved at some point of allocated 30GB HDD. Then I should be able to find that directory of the file on Windows. I'm really confused.

Am I thinking too simply? Or actually there is a complex hard disk allocating method of virtual machine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If helloworld.c is saved, it is saved at some point of allocated 30GB HDD. Then I should be able to find that directory of the file on windows.

You can see the data on your Windows laptop, but not as individual files – only as a *whole disk.*

Virtual machines work like real machines, in that the OS running inside the VM still thinks it has an actual HDD attached to it. Ubuntu doesn't tell VirtualBox to store individual files; it only talks to the virtual HDD in terms of sectors (the virtual disk has its own MBR, its own partitions, etc) – and much like a real HDD, VirtualBox has no idea what each sector means, it just stores them all in a single giant file.

Specifically, with VirtualBox, the virtual machine's data is stored in the `~\VirtualBox\` directory within your Windows account<sup>1</sup> (e.g. `C:\Users\sangyeob\VirtualBox\`). To find it, you can right-click a VM and select "Show in Explorer".

After opening that location, you should find a file `Ubuntu.vdi` or similar – it contains the entire "disk image" of your VM (with the MBR, the partition table, the filesystem, and everything). Your entire 30 GB disk space allocation is just this one .vdi file which VirtualBox pretends is a 30 GB HDD.

In other terms, the .vdi file is a lot like an .iso image, only containing an HDD instead of a CD.

(Though one difference is that .vdi files keep track of which parts of the virtual HDD haven't been written yet, which is why they start off a lot smaller than the actual "30 GB" allocation.)

---

There are exceptions to all of this, however. If you use VirtualBox's "Shared Folders" feature, you *can* allow the VM to directly access files on Windows.

"Shared folders" don't emulate disks; instead they practically emulate a network share, which *do* work in terms of files and not sectors.

For this feature to work, the VM might need the VirtualBox "Guest Additions" drivers to be installed, though recent Linux versions may already have support VirtualBox shared folders built-in.

---

<sup>1</sup> As a general guideline, programs avoid storing user data within "Program Files". Personal data is stored somewhere in your user account, while shared data would go in the hidden `C:\ProgramData\` directory (e.g. Hyper-V virtual machines are stored there by default).

Comment: Wow. Thank you for answering in detail. You hit the spot that I wondered. I totallly understand why I couldn't see the file and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you saved the file inside the VM, you should look inside the VM to find it.

You can't see guest files from the host, unless they reside
in a host folder that is shared with the VM.

The VM uses a virtual disk that has format that is identical to a physical
disk, including all sort of binary disk structures that cannot be read
directly.

If you mount the virtual disk in the host, it will be the same as adding
a new physical disk to the host.

Comment: NOTE HERE: Mounting the virtual disk in both HOST and GUEST **at the same time** might be a very bad idea. Use a share of some sort.

Comment: @Hannu: I'm not sure that it's even possible to mount both at the same time. I believe that most VM place an exclusive lock on their hard disk when the VM is running.

Comment: Indeed, it might not. But then; I see "impossible" things many times a year...